# Drop file upload coming up as null in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I've got a form with a drag and drop file input, which I originally found here:

http://codepen.io/prasanjit/pen/NxjZMO

the form is as follows:

```
     <form method="POST"  action="{{ url('images/save') }}">
        <div class="file-drop-area">
           <span class="fake-btn">Choose file</span>
           <span class="file-msg js-set-number">or drag and drop file here</span>
           <input class="file-input" type="file" name="fileUpload">
        </div>
        <button>Save</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
     </form>
```

the JS is unchanged from the original pen:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var $fileInput = $('.file-input');
var $droparea = $('.file-drop-area');

// highlight drag area
$fileInput.on('dragenter focus click', function() {
  $droparea.addClass('is-active');
});

// back to normal state
$fileInput.on('dragleave blur drop', function() {
  $droparea.removeClass('is-active');
});

// change inner text
$fileInput.on('change', function() {
  var filesCount = $(this)[0].files.length;
  var $textContainer = $(this).prev('.js-set-number');

  if (filesCount === 1) {
    // if single file then show file name
    $textContainer.text($(this).val().split('\\').pop());
  } else {
    // otherwise show number of files
    $textContainer.text(filesCount + ' files selected');
  }
});

});
```

The problem is, when I pass this through a controller, the file comes up as null when using

```
$file = $request->file('fileUpload');
```

however, when using

```
$file = $request->get('fileUpload');
```

and then die dumping $file, it turns out that the get request is actually getting the username. So it'll die dump something like "image01.jpg".

Furthermore, when adding validation to the form,

```
        $this->validate($request, [
            'fileUpload' => 'required',
        ]);
```

the form will only go through after you've attached a file.

So what's going on? Why is this coming up as null on a file request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form method="POST"  action="{{ url('images/save') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Right! Forgot about that! Thank you!

Comment: @FelixMaxime It's my pleasure. 
P.S. You can using `{{ csrf_field() }}` instead `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">`